# Job and Resource Scheduler

Tags: scheduler, job-scheduling

I am looking for some suggestions on a job scheduler for a stack of machines virtualized into one operating system (Suse) with synchronized cache (so you can access any memory from any process) with a few hundred processors. Ultimately what I would like to do is have multiple users submit jobs with a predetermined/expected execution time. I should be able to run something like

```
submit_job [-r <max_run_time_limit>] [-o <output_file>] [-i <input_file>] [-n <cpus_per_process>] [-t <threads_per_process>] [-j <jobname>] <my_program> [-arg <my_prog_arg>]
```

from the shell, and have the CPUs run the job uninterrupted until the end of the program or **max_run_time_limit**. Conversely, if other jobs from multiple users are occupying all CPUs, the job you submit must wait until other jobs are completed.

Ideally, in order to avoid users submitting jobs lasting a month on all CPUs, I would have a maximum allocated total run-time hours per user per month which the user cannot renew in that month without requesting additional hours from the administrator.

I am not very well versed in this subject so I'll provide more details if they are needed.

Comment: What is your question?  What programming language/environment are you using?  I think you will need to provide more details for this to be answerable and on-topic.

Comment: I'm not using a programming language. I am asking for suggestions using a scheduler that I can run like I showed in the command above. I'm looking for a shoftware name, link, etc.

Comment: It's a linux Suse environment.

Comment: StackOverflow is for programming questions, so I think this is off-topic.  You might consider [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/) for questions related to a server environment, however, like StackOverflow, that site [defines](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic) questions asking for recommendations as opinion-based and off-topic.  Any questions about a scheduler like this really require you to either already know what scheduler you'll be using, or be trying to implement your own.

Comment: Alright, good point. Thanks.